# What options do I have for displaying hierarchical data?

Tags: html, css, hierarchy

I have a bunch of hierarchical data that I'm trying to represent using HTML, JS, and JQuery. I've decided to use a left-floated div container system instead of a grid system to make the code easier to generate recursively. The problem is that I have some constraints; for example, I want the width of the tree to fit exactly into the client window. I can accomplish this by dynamically setting the width for each div when it's created in the JS. The width is calculated in percentage by counting the number of siblings an element has and diving 100 by that number of siblings.

The problem with this approach is that it wastes a lot of precious space. Even if an element has no children, it get's the same amount of space as all of its siblings. Once you get down to level 4 or 5, space starts to become a serious commodity.

The other approach I've tried is to let the browser auto size everything. This is really nice because nothing gets any more space than it needs. The problem here is that I lose a lot of control over dynamic sizing; I need to be able to zoom in and out, as well as start at exactly 100% width as I mentioned before. Also, when the tree grows beyond the width of the page, the overflown divs are shifting down. I need them to scroll off the page horizontally.

So my question is... what options do I have for ensuring that my tree structure saves space, fits exactly in the client width, and allows for zooming via dynamic sizing?

Here's a screenshot of the hierarchical data:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xl239fthmxss2dw/yhH_TUYq93

Here's a simplified example of the kind of code I'm generating:

```
<div id="map" class="tag-container">
    <div class="tag">Level 0 data</div>
    <div class="tag-container">
        <div class="tag">Level 1 data</div>
        <div class="tag-container">
            <div class="tag">Level 2 data</div>
            <div class="tag-container">
                <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tag-container">
                <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
                <div class="tag-container">
                    <div class="tag">Level 4 data</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag-container">
            <div class="tag">Level 2 data</div>
            <div class="tag-container">
                <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tag-container">
                <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
                <div class="tag-container">
                    <div class="tag">Level 4 data</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the related CSS:

```
.tag-container {
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    width: 33.333%
}

.zoom {
    cursor: pointer
}

body {
    background-color: azure;
    overflow: scroll
}
```

Comment: Could `display: inline-table` solve your problem? http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block2.html
I'm not sure I understand exactly how you want to layout the tree.

Comment: That seems to be out-dated... Anyway, I added a screenshot of what the tree looks like. Each container holds a purple "tag" and all of its child containers with their own tags. All tags are floated left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not afraid to use css3, this is my suggestion:

Add a div grouping tag-containers that are at the same level. The above markup would then look like this:

```
<div id="map" class="tag-container">
        <div class="tag">Level 0 data</div>
        <div class="tag-container">
            <div class="tag">Level 1 data</div>
            <div class="tag-container-group">
                <div class="tag-container">
                    <div class="tag">Level 2 data</div>
                    <div class="tag-container-group">
                        <div class="tag-container">
                            <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tag-container">
                            <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
                            <div class="tag-container-group">
                                <div class="tag-container">
                                    <div class="tag">Level 4 data</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="tag-container">
                <div class="tag">Level 2 data</div>
                <div class="tag-container-group">
                    <div class="tag-container">
                        <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tag-container">
                        <div class="tag">Level 3 data</div>
                        <div class="tag-container-group">
                            <div class="tag-container">
                                <div class="tag">Level 4 data</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS

```
.tag {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.tag-container-group {
    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;

    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;

    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-orient:horizontal;
}
.tag-container-group > .tag-container {
    width: 1px;
    -moz-box-flex:1.0; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -ms-flex:1.0; /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    box-flex:1.0;
}
```

I haven't cross browser tested this. Only in chrome. Certainly it will be crippled in older IE versions, but maybe that is a trade off you are willing to do? Or you could consider an alternate style sheet using `display: inline-table` for these.

If you want the nodes to be sized relative to its content you should remove `width: 1px` in the `.tag-container-group > .tag-container`

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks!